# How do I stop characters moving in the console?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm rather new at C++ and am trying to make a maze game in the command line. It mostly works fine but whenever I move my character (or write anything else to that line) it moves whatever else is written back, which makes solving the maze quite difficult.

I've been adapting the code from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1e5wO7XR2w which doesn't seem to have this issue (though I'm sure I followed it correctly).
I'm writing using C++ withing Visual Studio 2017

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool gameover, win; //Condition for gameover or a win
const int width = 20; //Maze Width
const int height = 20; //Maze Height
int x, y, endX, endY; //Coordinates of diffrent objects
bool mazeWallX[20] = { false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}; //Layers of walls will build up the maze, the bool statments state where there are and arent any walls.
bool mazeWallY[20] = { true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false };

bool mazeWallX2[20] = { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };
bool mazeWallY2[20] = { true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true };

bool mazeWallX3[20] = { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };
bool mazeWallY3[20] = { false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true };

bool mazeWallX4[20] = { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false };
bool mazeWallY4[20] = { true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };

bool mazeWallX5[20] = { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false };
bool mazeWallY5[20] = { true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };

enum eDirection { STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
eDirection dir;
void Setup() //Occurs at start of game, setting initial conditions.
{
    gameover = false;
    win = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = 1;
    y = 1;
    endX = 18;
    endY = 18;

}
void Draw() //Draws the player and walls on board, in command line.
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < width+2; i++) //Draws top boarder
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) //Draws vertical walls, exit and player
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || (mazeWallX[j]&&mazeWallY[i]) || (mazeWallX2[j] && mazeWallY2[i]) || (mazeWallX3[j] && mazeWallY3[i]) || (mazeWallX4[j] && mazeWallY4[i]) || (mazeWallX5[j] && mazeWallY5[i])) //Will draw a wall as indicated by the
                cout << "#";

            if (i == y && j == x) //Draws player
                cout << "O";
            else if (i == endY && j == endX) //Draws exit
                cout << "E"; 
            cout << " ";

            if (j == width - 1)
                    cout << "#";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width+2; i++) //Bottom wall
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;

}
void Input() //Handles Controls
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch()) //Gets character key pressed.
        {
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 'a':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void Logic()
{
    switch (dir)
    {
    case UP:
        y--;
        break;
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (x > width || x<0 || y>height || y < 0) //Specifies conditions for gameover.
    {
        gameover = true;
    }
    if (x == endX && y == endY || (x == endX+1 && y == endY) || (x == endX && y == endY+1) || (x == endX - 1 && y == endY) || (x == endX && y == endY-1))
    {
        win = true;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Setup();
    while (!gameover && !win) //While the game hasn't been won or lost, it will keep on redrawing the map to the command line interface.
    {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
        _sleep(200); //This tells the system to wait before looping again, this reduces flickering, slows the character down and makes the game a little easier to control.

    }

    if (win == true)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations, you've reached the end!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The walls (#'s) should stay fixed... but they don't.

Comment: You're not gonna like it, but regular terminal API is mostly suited to linear logging of data, not interactive input. If you want to use it for games, it's best to use something like ncurses, or ditch the native terminal altogether and use a graphically-drawn terminal with "direct" character access.

Comment: You should look at libraries like ncurses that allow you to draw with characters onto a terminal. PS. My experience is old so there may be newer libraries that are better. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: Ask yourself, "How many characters do I write to the terminal each time thru the `j` loop?  How many should I be writing?"  They should be the same number, but aren't.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of support for Ncurses but a couple of questions since I'm a little confused, is it a standard library? I would love to use it but for this piece of I can only use standards.

Comment: Or use the Windows Console functions.

Comment: @Jimmy no it's not a part of the C++ standard. If you want standard C++ you're going to have to think about something less interactive. I would talk to your teacher to get an idea of what is possible and what is not.

Comment: @Jimmy If you can use only standard libraries, your code is already not allowed, as it uses [conio,h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h), not part of the standard library.

Comment: @JaMiT Whoops, didn't realize that. I just included it and it worked out of the box so I assumed it was part of the standard ones. I will have to check if the school computers allow it.

Answer (score 0):

In for loop give the condition of end point of your screen just like in graphics we can give getmaxx() to auto detect x co-ordinate max length of your screen like this you can add header file

graphics.h ##header file

And then use getmaxx() to detect x and then getmaxy() to detect y you can use if it is not work then comment me i will try it with my own .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've looked into the graphics.h header and it seems to be an old header which isn't included in the standard library so I'm unable to use it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've figured it out

```
void Draw() //Draws the player and walls on board, in command line.
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < width+2; i++) //Draws top boarder
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) //Draws vertical walls, exit and player
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || (mazeWallX[j]&&mazeWallY[i]) || (mazeWallX2[j] && mazeWallY2[i]) || (mazeWallX3[j] && mazeWallY3[i]) || (mazeWallX4[j] && mazeWallY4[i]) || (mazeWallX5[j] && mazeWallY5[i])) //Will draw a wall as indicated by the
                cout << "#";

            else if (i == y && j == x) //Draws player
                cout << "O";
            else if (i == endY && j == endX) //Draws exit
                cout << "E"; 
            else
                cout << " ";

            if (j == width - 1)
                    cout << "#";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width+2; i++) //Bottom wall
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;

}
```

I added an else in front of cout << " "; and changed //Draws Exit to and else if, so the correct number of characters are written per line. Thanks @1201ProgramAlarm for the reminder.